# Why did the comments disappeard

Tags: discussion

The question "[SQL Median function not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44150669/sql-median-function-not-working)" had comments that asked the user to clarify his question by adding sample data. I upvoted one of these comments.  Now I don't see neither sample data more these comments. Why were the comments deleted? I am interested if the user finally understood the request and denied to supply data and the writers deleted their comment or if somebody flagged this comments and a moderator deleted them (or any other possibility)? I am not sure if I should ask the OP for sample data in a comment.

Comment: You sure you're not thinking of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44118860/how-to-find-median-in-sql)?

Comment: @Shog9 Yes, you are right. The user reposted the question.

Comment: I merged the new post with the old.